# parsing resume tablewith HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Can you say me how to parse data from this link?
     http://www.e1.ru/business/job/resume.detail.php?id=956004

I tryed something like this

```
       var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html[1]/body[1]/table[5]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[2]/table[4]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/table[1]");
```

but it is not good variant.

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore but probably that's the best you're going to get, unless there's an ID or class which you could use to shorten this

Answer (score -1):

Abbath, I recommend using some 3rd party tools. which can extract data from HTML and then extract your required data. like egrabber, rchilli and many more . 
if you are looking for your own solution - then add a index of complete text,   and then catch them as XML - study DOM structure and pick out selective values.